# datepicker using tags span with onchange event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

i have a html like this. with span tag to display datepicker. it is working for displaying datepicker. but the problem is i want to make an alert when user change the date by using onchange. but it's not working

```
 <tr>
      <td class="align-right">
            Est Payment Date :
      </td>
      <td>
            <span id="spanEstPaymentDate" class="spanclick"></span>
      </td>
 </tr>
```

and the js like this

```
$("#spanEstPaymentDate").datepicker("EstPaymentDate");
```

i have try for this, by using class. but not working

```
 $(".spanclick").on('click', function () {
     alert('hello');
 });
```

and i try

> ```
> $('#spanEstPaymentDate').datepicker("EstPaymentDate").on('changeDate',
> ```
>
> function (ev) {
>           $('#spanEstPaymentDate').change();
>       });
>
> ```
> $('#spanEstPaymentDate').change(function () {
>     alert('hello');
> });
> ```

but not working. any idea ? very thanks :)

Comment: How's the `EstPaymentDate` function defined? Where are you initialising the datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(function(){
  $('#spanEstPaymentDate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
     alert('select!');
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: @lamerlamer..make sure you are using it inside document.ready..and what is "EstPaymentDate" in above question???

Comment: @lamerlamer...what is 'EstPaymentDate' in this statement '$("#spanEstPaymentDate").datepicker("EstPaymentDate")'...???